# Gerrit+Jenkins: communicate results of non-blocking jobs?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I have two jobs A and B. Job A is triggering job B, but does not wait for the result. How can I make job B now communicate back to Gerrit that that has also been done?

Do I have to use the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use API: `ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit review --message "Job B ran extremely well" <sha1>`

note 1: the quotes may be needed around the actual gerrit call

note 2: depending on branch strategy for your project you might also want to include `<change_id>` after `<sha1>`, since one sha1 may be present in different branches

Or make job A wait for job B's completion (one way is to turn on `block until the other projects complete` ).

The latter would be easier to use and gives more possibilities with reduced effort cost. The former, however, has an advantage of better customization.